# Bug in qTranslate-X plugin excerpt wordpress

Tags: wordpress

When qTranslate-X plugin is used in wordpress web site and you have lets say 3 languages take ge,it,en(german, italian,english) and when you make a post from wp-panel you will write content only on ge and it lang excerpt, when you will look on the site on the en section (that have the excerpt blank) it will display there the ge excerpt content.
If you actually write something in en excerpt it will be displayed, but the problem is when you left in blank, it will auto-generate ge excerpt(or it if don't have ge excerpt). 
I try to fix this with a advanced excerpt plugin, and actually look and try to edit the php conf files of the qTranslate-X plugin (things are evan more messy there), what I want when you don't complete the en excerpt(or any lang excerpt) to display the message Sorry, this entry is only available in *lang you have* and *lang you have*. This message should be auto displayed by the qTranslate-X plugin, if you don't complete neither ge,it and en excerpt, it will actually display there correct massage! Sorry, this entry is only available in German and Italian.

Answer (score 0):

You need to go to the MySQL table wp_posts and change the post_excerpt field from TEXT to LONGTEXT type. I did so and now all works fine